# How to get the exact bending of curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to get the following figure:

[image]

What I have done is given below:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[%x=2cm,y=2cm
        dot/.style = {circle, fill,
                      inner sep=.3ex,
                      }
                            ]
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (-1,0)--(4,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (0,-4)--(0,4) node [above] {$y$};
    \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (0, 0) circle (.3ex);
        \draw[scale=1] (0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$O$} ;
        \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (3,3.25) circle (.3ex);
        \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (0,3.25) circle (.3ex);
        %right direction below x axis
        \draw[thin, draw=black,dashed] (0,3.25)--(3,3.25) node [right] {$A$};
        \draw[scale=1,blue!90!blue,thick,rounded corners] (3,3.25) to[bend right=10] (.1,2.75) to (.1,-2.75)  to[bend right=10] (3,-3.25);
         \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

How to get the exact bending as the figure above together with the arrows?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to increase the radius of the `rounded corner`s. I'd also use the `dot`s which you define, also in order to prevent curve from entering the dots.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%x=2cm,y=2cm
    dot/.style = {circle, fill=red,
                  inner sep=.3ex,node contents={}
                  }
                        ]
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (-1,0)--(4,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (0,-4)--(0,4) node [above] {$y$};
    %right direction below x axis
    \path    (0,0) node[dot,label=below left:{$O$}];
    \draw[thin, draw=black,dashed] (0,3.25) node[dot]
         --(3,3.25) node(A)[dot,label=right:{$A$}] 
         (0,-3.25) node[dot] -- (3,-3.25)node(B)[dot] ;
    \draw[blue!90!blue,thick,rounded corners=25pt,
        >={Stealth[length=3mm]},postaction=decorate,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{>}},
    mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{>}},
    mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{>}},
    mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}},
    }] 
     (A) to[bend right=10] (.2,2.5) -- (.2,-2.5)  
     to[bend right=10] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's my best effort, using the function $x=y^6+0.1$ (a higher order polynomial will produce something more "square"). I've changed your coordinates so that the node `A` is at (1.1,1), which makes plotting the curve a bit easier.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,%x=2cm,y=2cm
        dot/.style = {circle, fill,
                      inner sep=.3ex,
                      }
                            ]
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (-0.1,0)--(1.25,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (0,-1.25)--(0,1.25) node [above] {$y$};
    \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (0, 0) circle (.3ex);
        \draw[scale=1] (0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$O$} ;
        \draw[thin, draw=black,dashed] (0,1)--(1.1,1) node [right] {$A$};
        \draw[thin, draw=black,dashed] (0,-1)--(1.1,-1);
        \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (1.1,1) circle (.3ex);
        \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (0,1) circle (.3ex);
        \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (0,-1) circle (.3ex);
        %right direction below x axis
        \draw[domain=-1:1,smooth,variable=\y,blue,thick]  plot ({pow(\y, 6)+0.1},{\y});
         \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I also changed the order of some of the elements, so that the red circles are on top of the dashed lines. Ideally you'd probably also have the red circles drawn after the blue curve, but I'll leave that to you to fix.

[image: Curve]

Comment: Note that `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` isn't used here and that `pow(\y, 6)` can advantageously replace `\y*\y*\y*\y*\y*\y`.

Comment: Good point, I'll adjust...

Comment: You can add very short arrows at various points along the line (tangents).  Note that pow is implemented using polynomial approximations for `exp(6*log(\y))` and is probably slower and less accurate than `\y*\y*\y*\y*\y*\y`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Domain of y=-1:1, and log will be undefined for y<0... Is it not?

Comment: IIRC, they recently updated pow() to use sign(\y)*exp(6*\log(abs(\y))) or something like that.  The old version did not work for negative values.